# Как изменить список так, чтобы он сохранился?

Tags: python, list

Как изменить список так, чтобы его первая версия осталась прежней, а вторая была изменена?

Код:

```
depthb = max(depth["bids"]) #Ищем самые большие цены на покупку
depths = max(depth["asks"]) #Ищем самые большие цены на продаже

print(depthb) #Выводим список на покупку
del depthb[0] #Удаляем первый элемент(цена)
print(depthb) #Выводим список на покупку после изменения
```

Логи:

```
['2.05200000', '6332.80000000'] #1-цена 2-ставка
['6332.80000000'] #только ставка
```

И мне тоесть надо так, чтобы после изменения списка цен на покупку, этот список остался неизменный, а измененный список сохранялся в другую переменную.

Comment: `new_depthb = depthb[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вашим способом:

```
depthb = max(depth["bids"]) #Ищем самые большие цены на покупку
depths = max(depth["asks"]) #Ищем самые большие цены на продаже

print(depthb) #Выводим список на покупку
depthb2=depthb[:]
del depthb2[0] #Удаляем первый элемент(цена)
print(depthb2) #Выводим список на покупку после изменения
```

Или можно, как сказал @GrAnd:

```
depthb2 = depthb[1:]
```